# Weird JSON behavior when requesting a json file via $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a json file (text2.json) and a text file (text2.txt) which has the exact same content as text2.json.

I found it quite interesting when requesting json file via $.ajax:

Requesting text2.json to web server:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "./scripts/text2.json",
   dataType:"json",
   success: function(data){
            alert('success');
   },
   error: function(){alert('error');}
 });
```

This alerts error.

Requesting text2.txt to web server:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "./scripts/text2.txt",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
            alert('success');
    },
    error: function(){alert('error');}
  });
```

This alerts success.

As of now, I only have 2-day javascript experience and I was just wondering what causes this trade-off...

**EDIT**

For text2.json + type:"json", I revised my alert() in error: as you guys suggested. Then the alert gives "[object object]" as my json file is "{"result":true, "count":2}".That just looks like an empty object or something.

Then I detected there's a "parseerror" when requesing text2.json as json dataType. I am not sure about this info. Looks like some initial settings is incorrect. Anyone wanna give me a hint?

Looks like my json file is so much like a malformed json. That might be the case ...

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a difference between the 2 files?

Comment: and what is the error that it returns?

Comment: @romo im pretty sure that both files have the exact same content.

Comment: actually no error returns @AbrahamP . I set up alert() for success and error so all I got is just info from alert().

Comment: what browser are you working in?

Comment: What type of web server are you using, and what happens when you make the request without ajax?

Comment: chrome.no exceptions and errors really captured by chrome.

Comment: Try swapping extensions and see if you get the same result.

Comment: the error could be an exception as well, try **error:function(response){ alert(response); }**

Comment: You can get the details of the error function `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ then tell us what the error is

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is related to the headers of the response. You are specifying a json datatype, thus the expected headers should be of type `application/json`